# Module for replacing data in read-only fields in SuiteScript 2.0?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to build a Netsuite script to do the following:

1. Load a saved search with transaction records
2. [Update value in the (read-only) "URL" field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fgzj.png) with a new hyperlink from a CSV list

I'm unable to find a SuiteScript 2.0 module which can interact with this read-only field. Here's the code I've been testing in the console so far. It successfully loads the saved search and results set in the browser console using the `results.columns` format (including an Internal File ID and the existing URL), but I'm not sure which module will allow me to actually replace that value with a new value.

```
 /**
 *  @NApiVersion 2.0
 *  @NScriptType ClientScript
 *
 *  1. Load saved search for files to update
 *  2. For each record in saved search, set URL field to new URL value  
 */

require(['N/search', 'N/file'], function(search, file) {
    var searchobj = search.load({
        id: 'customsearch_url'
    })
    var results=searchobj.run();
        console.log(results);
    results.each(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        var URL = result.getValue(results.columns[4])
        console.log(URL);
        var fileId = result.getValue(results.columns[3])
        var fileObj = file.load({
            id: fileId
        })
        console.log(fileObj)
        return true;
    });
});
```

What's the best way to write this script to replace the value in the `URL` field with a new hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

To create/update/delete any record in NetSuite you need to use [N/record](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4267255811.html) module.
First you should load/create a record which would return record object and then you can use [record.setValue](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273155868.html) function to set/update values.

Or if you only want to update body fields, you can use [record.submitFields](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4267283788.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you, that helps point me in the right direction. Do you know if the N/record module is also capable of reading input from CSV's? The list of new hyperlinks is currently stored in a CSV file (there are thousands of values), so I was hoping to set the script to load this file, as well.

Comment: No, to read contents from a file, you have to use N/file as you have already.

Comment: On a separate note if you have all the new values in csv file, you should take a look at csv import.

Comment: Netsuite support told me the CSV import isn't an option because that field is read-only. The only way to update it with those values would be through a Suitescript. Unfortunately, I'm also not sure this is possible to do with Suitescript. The N/record module seems to be what I need, but since it can't read values from a CSV, that doesn't work, either. I would need a module that can read CSV values, then replace the values in a specific field of a saved search with these CSV values.

Comment: As per the other answer, you CANNOT overwrite the File Record URL fields

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible, NS URLs are system generated and cannot be updated/edited. That is the reason why it is (Read-Only), meaning you can ONLY read the data.